# Start and wait for wifi connectivity - threading

Tags: android, multithreading

I've written the code which starts wifi and then checks (every second) if the wifi is connected. The problem is it holds the main thread until the connection is available. I need a help with threading this code.

```
// Sevice
// wifi checking part
    ConnectivityManager Cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo Ni = Cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    WifiManager wiM = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    wiM.setWifiEnabled(true);


        int i=0;

        while (Ni == null)   {
           Ni = Cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            i++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i > 29) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(Ni.isConnected())    {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

            noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("app")
                    .setContentText("running")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
                    .build();

            startForeground(12345, noti);

            new myTask().execute(httpAddress);
            DelayedShutdown(millis);

        } else {


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helper class might be able to help you

https://gist.github.com/bclymer/6708605

Mainly the `runInBackgroundThenUi()` method, put the code that waits for the WiFi in a runnable in the background param, then the code to run after the wifi connects in the ui param.

Like this

```
ThreadManager.runInBackgroundThenUi(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // wait for that tasty WiFi
    }
}, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // GUYS I HAVE THE WIFI!!
    }
});
```

Disclaimer, I wrote this class. I use it in a lot (all) of my apps though.

Comment: Thanks. It works! This class should be included in the Android's API.

Comment: hi thanks for the helper class, i have an issue, i check network connectivity using connection manager and return true & in my app i use the return value in **if statement** and then update my app from network. what problem i get is if after returning true to the if statement the network goes off, my app continues to run forever without exiting. what can i do?